# Google analytics show different visits count than Blogger stats count

Tags: google-analytics, blogger

I have installed Google Analytics tracking code in my blogger blog. Bloggers own stats show one count and Google analytics tracking shows different count. 
Blogger stats always shows higher visit count than Google analytics tracking report. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No two stats packages will give you the exact same numbers for several reasons:

1. They may define a "visit" differently
2. They may use different tracking methods
3. One or the other could be using sampled data

And users could be clicking away before one of them has the opportunity to record the visit.

So, it's apples and oranges. Pick one to go with and look for trends over time rather than exact numbers. They should be trending in the same direction.

Since the actual or percentage difference wasn't mentioned in the question, one can only guess as to whether or not this is a negligible or accepted difference.

Comment: providing two options for tracking confuses me.... It seems like their algorithm is different for blogger... not based on real statistics...

Answer (score 0):

A possibility could be that you have set blogger stats to not count your own visits and analytics could be counting them or vica versa.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you insert in your pages to let GA to track the traffic is javascript code.
I think GA counts less hits because there are some browsers that blocks javascript code. It depends on the config of every system so could explain the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I had this question as well. Not only do the counts differ but so do the locations. Blogger always seems so much more optimistic too! Here's an article which explained it pretty well ... http://morefromyourblog.com/why-do-google-analytics-stats-differ-from-blogger-stats/